# Python Selenium bot to view Instagram stories | How can i click the profiles of people that have active stories?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram, instagram-story

I have this Instagram bot that is made using Python and Selenium, It log into Instagram, goes to a profile, select the last post and select the "other x people liked this photo" to show the complete list of the people that liked the post(it can be done with the follower of the page too).

Now I am stuck because I don't know how can i make the bot click only the profiles that have active stories and how to make it scroll down (the problem is that the way that i found to click on the profiles works just with the first one profile because when I click on the profile it opens the stories and closes the post, so when i reopen the post and the list of like on this post it will reclick on the same profile that I have already seen the stories of).

Does someone know how to do that or a similar thing maybe something even better that I didn't thinked of?

I don't think code is needed but if you need I will post it, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the "back" button on your browser window? Or open the page in a new tab, so you have still the old one to go back to.